# xml database URL configuration

Tags: database, exist-db

I am using eXml database in my project. I want access my url http://mysystemIp:8080/db but now I am accessing http://mysystemIp:8080/exist/test/data. How I Can change the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use a reverse proxy - http://www.exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/production_web_proxying